# Cordova video chat with ConnectyCube: can't build on Xcode 9

Tags: ios, cordova, connectycube

I'm trying to build ConnectyCube Video chat code sample under Cordova
https://developers.connectycube.com/js/code-samples-videochat-cordova

but getting an error: "The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a 
supported value for targets which use Swift. This setting can be set in the build settings editor."

I'm using Xcode 9.3.
Tried to set Swift Language Version in Build Settings to Swift 3.3 - but got tons of Xcode errors, e.g.:
- Use of undeclared types
- Use of unresolved identifier etc.

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably you did not follow the Building Steps of **cordova-plugin-iosrtc**

https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/blob/master/docs/Building.md

and did not setup properly a hook **hooks/iosrtc-swift-support.js**

With this hook it should work without any issues, because it adds Swift 3.0 settings which this plugin supports well

All these steps are listed here https://developers.connectycube.com/js/code-samples-videochat-cordova